# Pass method chains to to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I know you can pass methods the values of which you want to be available to json objects like so:

```
# user.rb
def name
  first_name + last_name
end

# some controller
render :json => @user.to_json(:methods => :name)
```

But if I want to massage the value returned from the method a bit (with a text helper say) is there a way to do that?  I guess another way to ask this is does `#to_json` support arbitrary attributes?  If not, why not?  Has anyone else ran into this before?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "render :json" to specify arbitrary attributes in the JSON output.  Here is an example:

```
render :json => { :arbitraryAttribute => arbitrary_method_to_call(), :user => @user.to_json }
```

The above code would generate JSON like the following:

```
{
    "arbitraryAttribute":"returnValueOfMethodCall",
    "user":{ the result of @user.to_json }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been doing, but it would just be so much nicer to access those attributes as properties on the user object, because that's what they are...

Comment: This doesn't work because `@user.to_json` will return a string. When `render :json` receives that string, the `@user` JSON is escaped.